# Image manipulation using Node.js on Azure website

Tags: node.js, azure, imagemagick, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing a web project using Node.js where users can set their profile image by uploading it to the server.

I need to perform basic manipulation on those images (resize and crop), and then store them into a blob.

I usually use GraphicsMagic or ImageMagick to achieve this kind of tasks, but I want to publish this project on Microsoft Azure website.

Is there a known and safe way to manipulate images serverside into an Azure website using Node.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can [use node modules with Azure Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/). However you cannot install any third party apps on the Web Sites (thus no ImageMagick or Graphics Magic).

Looking out in the wild, you may find some [native node modules that does not require external components to manipulate images](http://eyalarubas.com/image-processing-nodejs.html) like the [lwip](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) and probably some more. Just find your module that is not dependent on external third party libraries and is fully self contained.

Answer (score 0):

I made imagemagick work on azure websites by using site extension.

You can check the repository for more info:

https://github.com/fatihturgut/azure-imagemagick-nodejs