# How to convert PDF to Image using Nodejs on Azure Web app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to convert pdf file to png files using Nodejs. Normally, I can do it by using [Imagemagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick) module locally. However, I did some [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150375/image-manipulation-using-node-js-on-azure-website), and found out that I can not use third party apps like ImageMagick or Graphics Magic on Azure Web app.

Answer (score 3):

Try **[App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-intro)**, the ImageMagick libs are in by default with the built-in Docker images. Works out of the box.

Here's the base image they use for Node:
https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/Dockerfile#L25

And here's a sample i wrote:
https://github.com/snobu/gifinator

If you really **really** want to run ImageMagick on Windows (although for your own sanity i would advise against), check out this guide i wrote for App Service — it's for PHP but should be a good starting point for Node as well:
https://github.com/snobu/php-imagick-webapps

Comment: Thanks, the problem is my current system is deployed on a Windows Webapp. I can not move the whole system to Linux webapp just because of this converting feature :(

Comment: What dependency do you have on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library PDF-Poppler

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-poppler

Sample Code

```
const path = require('path');
const pdf = require('pdf-poppler');
 
let file = 'C:\\PDF2TIFF\\sample.pdf'
 
let opts = {
    format: 'png',
    out_dir: path.dirname(file),
    out_prefix: path.basename(file, path.extname(file)),
    page: null
}
 
pdf.convert(file, opts)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Successfully converted');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
```